# Loopback APIs and promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, loopback

In the loopback documentation, it says 
"The following built-in models support the promises API:
User 
Application 
PersistedModel"

So if in a unit test, I want to create a user, then log that user in, then how come using the callback method works:

```
aUser.create({email: 'user3@bar.com', password: 'foo'}, function() {
                aUser.login({email: 'user3@bar.com', password: 'foo'}, 'user', function (err, res) {
                    // stuff
                });
            });
```

but using promises doesn't:

```
var Promise = require ('bluebird');
aUser.create({email: 'foo@bar.com', password: 'bar'})
                .then(function(err, res){
                    aUser.login({email: 'foo@bar.com', password: 'bar'}, 'user');
                })
                .then(function(err, res) {
                    //stuff
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    console.error(err);
                });
```

I've also tried Promise.join, Promise.mapSeries.

Comment: "doesn't work" how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Your promises code doesn't do the same thing as your non-promises code. In your non-promises code, you don't do "stuff" until `aUser.login` completes successfully, but in your promises code you're not waiting for that. To do the same thing, your first `then` callback needs to **return** the promise that `aUser.login` returns. Otherwise, the promise your first call to `then` returns is resolved with the value `undefined`, rather than settling based on the resolution or rejection of the `aUser.login` promise.
2. The arguments you're declaring for your `then` callbacks are incorrect: The resolution callback receives a **single** argument, which is the resolved value. It's not like a NodeJS callback that receives two.

So (see lines tagged with `***`):

```
var Promise = require ('bluebird');
aUser.create({email: 'foo@bar.com', password: 'bar'})
    .then(function(res){                                                     // ***
        return aUser.login({email: 'foo@bar.com', password: 'bar'}, 'user'); // ***
    })
    .then(function(res){                                                     // ***
        //stuff
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.error(err);
    });
```

---

Side note: If you're not using `Promise` in your code, no need to require it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - apologies, couple of typos in the Promise example with regard arguments, but I appreciate the feedback

Comment: @stephenwil: No worries. The first item above is probably what's wrong.